# Access SQL: How to group and pick distinct values in each group?

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, distinct

I'm struggling on an Access SQL statement. I tried to find some answer here but no question seemed to cover what I mean:

I need to group records by some Title, then in each group I want to pick only 1 (the first) occurrence of the Part, like:

```
Title | Part
--------------
one       A
one       A
one       B
one       B
one       C
one       C
-------------
two       A
two       A
two       B
two       B
two       C
two       C

Wished Result:

Title | Part
--------------
one       A
one       B
one       C
-------------
two       A
two       B
two       C
```

I'd be glad about any help:)

I tried so far several combinations of GROUP BY, ORDER BY, DISTINCT but nothing lead to a result.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT title,part FROM t GROUP BY title,part
```

Answer (score 1):

Hoping i understood question correctly.

Tried to create similar situation. Please check below query.

Rextester Link - http://rextester.com/TNSME52397

```
create table test
(

    col1 varchar(100),
    col2 varchar(100)


    )


insert into test values('one','A');
insert into test values('one','A');
insert into test values('one','B');
insert into test values('one','B');
insert into test values('one','C');
insert into test values('one','C');
insert into test values('two','A');
insert into test values('two','A');
insert into test values('two','B');
insert into test values('two','B');
insert into test values('two','C');
insert into test values('two','C');


select col1 , col2 from
(
select col1 , col2 ,
row_number()over (partition by col1,col2 order by col1,col2) rn
from test
) a
where rn =1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct title, part from table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table test
(

    col1 varchar(100),
    col2 varchar(100)


    )


insert into test values('one','A');
insert into test values('one','A');
insert into test values('one','B');
insert into test values('one','B');
insert into test values('one','C');
insert into test values('one','C');
insert into test values('two','A');
insert into test values('two','A');
insert into test values('two','B');
insert into test values('two','B');
insert into test values('two','C');
insert into test values('two','C');


select unique col1 , col2,rn from
(
select col1 , col2 ,
dense_rank()over (partition by col1,col2 order by col1,col2) rn
from test
) a
where rn =1
;
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it. Code-only answers are not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT col1,col2,
    RANK() over(partition by col1,col2
                ORDER BY ROWNUM) R
FROM test)
where R=1;


SELECT * FROM test
WHERE ROWID IN (
SELECT MIN(ROWID)
FROM test
GROUP BY col1,col2)
ORDER BY col1,col2;

SELECt * FROM test A
WHERE 1 = ( SELECT COUNT(1) 
            FROM test B 
            WHERE A.col1 = B.col1
            AND A.col2 = B.col2
            AND A.ROWID >= B.ROWID);
            
            
SELECT col1,col2
FROM test
UNION 
SELECT NULL,NULL
FROM DUAL WHERE 1=2;
```